# Android Studio can't find property XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I'm having a very similar issue to this post - [Java and Xerces: can't find property XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53299280/java-and-xerces-cant-find-property-xmlconstants-access-external-dtd) - but with working on Android Studio IDE.

I'm also trying to fix the same issue about disabling XML external entity (XXE) processing that gets raised as a vulnerability in our SonarCloud analysis (see: https://sonarcloud.io/project/issues?id=org.digitalcampus.mobile.learning&open=AW3ezGnx-dJmagWAiKPH&resolved=false&types=VULNERABILITY).

As far as I can tell, I have the most recent version of Android Studio installed, along with the all recent updates for Java, my Android Studio about dialog shows this:

```
Android Studio 3.5.3
Build #AI-191.8026.42.35.6010548, built on November 15, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.15.0-76-generic
```

I'd really appreciate any feedback/help on how I can resolve this, so I can remove the vulnerability from my code. Just let me know if there is any other specific information (versions etc) that you may need.

Thanks in advance for you help...

**Update** (14/2/20)...
Looks like the ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD constant is not available in Android - see the Android java reference docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/XMLConstants.html.

So would the FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING constant be sufficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the below code to solve your issue, check the [XML External Entity Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/XML_External_Entity_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html) for more details

```
 DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    String FEATURE = null;
    try {
       
        dbf.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl", true);
        dbf.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", false);
        dbf.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities", false);
        dbf.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
        dbf.setXIncludeAware(false);
        dbf.setExpandEntityReferences(false);
        

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // This should catch a failed setFeature feature
        

    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // On Apache, this should be thrown when disallowing DOCTYPE

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // XXE that points to a file that doesn't exist

    }

// Load XML file or stream using a XXE agnostic configured parser...
        DocumentBuilder safebuilder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
```

if this was helpful, please mark this as the answer.

Comment: just what I needed... it's now no longer showing as a vulnerability (on the instance I've tested on anyway). I did get the message that the SAXException and IOException aren't thrown in that particular try block, so I didn't need to include these catches.