# How to deploy WAR in Jboss EAP 7.1 without errors

Tags: java, spring, maven, jboss

The server is Jboss EAP 7.1.
The app was created with  Java, maven, Spring boot, Hibernate and contained in War. The war is put in deploy directory, but when i try to run the server appears the error

I tried to deploy a war in JBoss, but it generates the following error

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
11:55:54,156 ERROR [org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Application run failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'payloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/ws/config/annotation/DelegatingWsConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping]: Factory method 'payloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:157)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:137)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:192)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:174)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:239)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:99)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping]: Factory method 'payloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.WsConfigurationSupport.payloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping(WsConfigurationSupport.java:94)
    at org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9aed24d9.CGLIB$payloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping$6(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9aed24d9$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2c59c79d.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363)
    at org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9aed24d9.payloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No soportado: http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD
    at org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl.setAttribute(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:580)
    at __redirected.__TransformerFactory.setAttribute(__TransformerFactory.java:170)
    at org.springframework.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryUtils.defaultSettings(TransformerFactoryUtils.java:53)
    at org.springframework.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryUtils.newInstance(TransformerFactoryUtils.java:32)
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping.<clinit>(PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping.java:58)
    ... 51 more

11:55:54,156 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/botonDeRedencion-3.0.7.BUILD-SNAPSHOT": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/botonDeRedencion-3.0.7.BUILD-SNAPSHOT": java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'payloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/ws/config/annotation/DelegatingWsConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping]: Factory method 'payloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:84)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'payloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/ws/config/annotation/DelegatingWsConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping]: Factory method 'payloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:241)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:99)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'payloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/ws/config/annotation/DelegatingWsConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping]: Factory method 'payloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:157)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:137)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:192)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:174)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:239)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping]: Factory method 'payloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.WsConfigurationSupport.payloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping(WsConfigurationSupport.java:94)
    at org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9aed24d9.CGLIB$payloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping$6(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9aed24d9$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2c59c79d.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363)
    at org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9aed24d9.payloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No soportado: http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD
    at org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl.setAttribute(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:580)
    at __redirected.__TransformerFactory.setAttribute(__TransformerFactory.java:170)
    at org.springframework.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryUtils.defaultSettings(TransformerFactoryUtils.java:53)
    at org.springframework.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryUtils.newInstance(TransformerFactoryUtils.java:32)
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping.<clinit>(PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping.java:58)
    ... 51 more

11:55:54,172 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operación ("deploy") falló - dirección: ([("deployment" => "botonDeRedencion-3.0.7.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war")]) - descripción de la falla: {"WFLYCTL0080: Servicios fallidos" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host.\"/botonDeRedencion-3.0.7.BUILD-SNAPSHOT\"" => "java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'payloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/ws/config/annotation/DelegatingWsConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping]: Factory method 'payloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'payloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/ws/config/annotation/DelegatingWsConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping]: Factory method 'payloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'payloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/ws/config/annotation/DelegatingWsConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping]: Factory method 'payloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping]: Factory method 'payloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No soportado: http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD"}}
11:55:54,219 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYSRV0010: Implementado "botonDeRedencion-3.0.7.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name : "botonDeRedencion-3.0.7.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war")
11:55:54,219 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Reporte del estatus del servicio
WFLYCTL0186: Servicios que no lograron iniciar:      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/botonDeRedencion-3.0.7.BUILD-SNAPSHOT": java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'payloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/ws/config/annotation/DelegatingWsConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping]: Factory method 'payloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

11:55:54,328 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Reanudando el servidor
11:55:54,344 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Interfaz de administración http escuchando en http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
11:55:54,344 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Consola de administración escuchando en http://127.0.0.1:9990
11:55:54,344 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: JBoss EAP 7.1.0.GA (WildFly Core 3.0.10.Final-redhat-1)  inició (con errores) en 24204ms - Inició 502 de 733 servicios (2 servicios fallaron o faltan dependencias, 353 servicios son perezosos, pasivos o por demanda)
```

Please help me with this

Comment: Spring seems to be having a hard time auto wiring your class `PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping`.

Comment: It seems to be related to XML option "http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalSchema". Are you running on Java 8 ? Is your war containing xml related libs ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TransformerFactory and Xalan Dependency Conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45152707/transformerfactory-and-xalan-dependency-conflict)